# Stuffing optional parameter in LINQ where statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have a LINQ where statement for a few parameter based on which I filter results like this:

```
 .Where(x=> x.Sales>0 && (filterWord=="" ||x.Title.Contains(filterWord.ToLower())))
  .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Sales)
  .Skip(skip)
  .Take(pageSize);
```

I'd like to filter out all the products which meet the requirement either way (>0 sales)... But, for the filter word parameter, if its =="", then I don't want to take into the account that parameters. On the contra if the parameter is !="" I'd like to filter out my collection based on that parameter + products that have at least 1 sale.

Is this doable via Where method, and if so how ?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work, here is another way

```
.Where(x=> x.Sales>0 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterWord) || x.Title.Contains(filterWord.ToLower())))
```

Comment: It looks good this way, i'll just test out with optional parameter there

Answer (score 1):

```
.Where(x => filterWord == "" || (x.Title.Contains(filterWord.ToLower()) && x.Sales.Any())) .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sales) .Skip(skip) .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: you write: x.Sales > 0. So x.Sales is a number, or at least comparable to a number. You also use x.Sales.Any(). So x.Sales implements IEnumerable, or in words: it represents a sequence. Can a sequence be compared to a number?

Comment: It's a mistake: `.Where(x => filterWord == "" || (x.Title.Contains(filterWord.ToLower()) && x.Sales.Any()))
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sales)
  .Skip(skip)
  .Take(pageSize);`

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, it would either match empty string **or** not empty string and title filter.

```
.Where(x=> x.Sales > 0 && ((filterWord == "") || (filterWord != "" && x.Title.Contains(filterWord)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to make the data server do something that's best done in code?

```
string filterWord = "m2";

IQueryable<MyTable> q = db.MyTables;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterWord))
    q = q.Where(t=> t.Sales > 0 && t.Title.Contains(filterWord.ToLower()));

q = q.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Sales)
     .Skip(skip)
     .Take(pageSize);

q.Dump();
```

UPDATE:

```
IQueryable<MyTable> q = db.MyTables.Where(t=> t.Sales > 0);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterWord))
    q = q.Where(t=>t.Title.Contains(filterWord.ToLower()));
```

The two consecutive `Where()`s will act as an And.

Comment: Hey James, thanks for the reply... What about the case when the filter word is not there ?:)

Comment: @User987 Your question is a bit confusingly worded --- I'm going by the spec: if filterWord == "", all items; if filterWord !="", items with at least one sold, and match filterWord.  If you want something else, please clarify.

Comment: I think this is slightly incorrect: the filter on `Sales`, i.e. `t=> t.Sales > 0`, should be applied unconditionally, while here it is applied only together with non-empty `filterWord`.